# Retrieving value of a method with Predicate return type in java

Tags: java, class, methods, predicate

I am working on a pre-existing java program, one of its classes calculates some Boolean features. Some private methods do this. Their return type is Predicate. For example :

```
 private Predicate<ChunkedBinaryExtraction> startArg1() {
        return new Predicate<ChunkedBinaryExtraction>() {
            public boolean apply(ChunkedBinaryExtraction e) {
                return e.getArgument1().getRange().getStart() == 0;
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to retrieve this feature value, I used this simple statements:

```
Predicate<ChunkedBinaryExtraction> ftr1=startArg1();
System.out.print("Feature1 is: "+ftr1);
```

The result should return a Boolean value :`true or false`, but it shows:

```
Feature1 is: edu.washington.cs.knowitall.extractor.conf.ReVerbFeatures$3@1eb44e46
```

I'm new to Java programming, please help:( Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an object. So the `print` will call `toString()` on the predicate object. I guess you want the result of the `apply` method, so you need to do sth. like this

```
ChunkedBinaryExtraction someObject = ...
Predicate<ChunkedBinaryExtraction> ftr1 = startArg1();
System.out.print("Feature1 is: " + ftr1.apply(someObject));
```

Where the `ChunkedBinaryExtraction` object comes from, you have to know.